# Create table from dictionary data in a safe way

Tags: python, sql-injection, psycopg2

I have a problem where i have a list of dictionaries with for example the following data:

```
columns = [{
    'name': 'column1',
    'type': 'varchar'
},
{
    'name': 'column2',
    'type': 'decimal'
},
.
.
.
]
```

From that list i need to dynamically create a CREATE TABLE statement based on each dictionary in the list which contains the name of the column and the type and execute it on a PostgreSQL database using the psycopg2 adapter.

I managed to do it with:

```
columns = "(" + ",\n".join(["{} {}".format(col['name'], col['type']) for col in columns]) + ")"
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE some_table_name\n {}".format(columns))
```

But this solution is vulnerable to SQL injection. I tried to do the exact same thing with the sql module from psycopg2 but without luck. Always getting syntax error, because it wraps the type in quotes.

Is there some way this can be done safely?

Comment: Can you post your attempts using `psycopg2.sql`.

Comment: 'columns' has unquotes strings: is it intentional?

Comment: Don't have time for a complete example, but a quick example: `print(sql.SQL('decimal').as_string(con))                                                                                                                                  
decimal`

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [AsIs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.AsIs) to get the column types added non-quoted:

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extensions import AsIs
import psycopg2.sql as sql

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=mf port=5959 host=localhost user=mf_usr")

columns = [{
    'name': "column1",
    'type': "varchar"
},
{
    'name': "column2",
    'type': "decimal"
}]

# create a dict, so we can use dict placeholders in the CREATE TABLE query.
column_dict = {c['name']: AsIs(c['type']) for c in columns}

createSQL = sql.SQL("CREATE TABLE some_table_name\n ({columns})").format(
    columns = sql.SQL(',').join(
        sql.SQL(' ').join([sql.Identifier(col), sql.Placeholder(col)]) for col in column_dict)
)

print(createSQL.as_string(conn))
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(createSQL, column_dict)
cur.execute("insert into some_table_name (column1) VALUES ('foo')")
cur.execute("select * FROM some_table_name")
print('Result: ', cur.fetchall())
```

Output:

```
CREATE TABLE some_table_name
 ("column1" %(column1)s,"column2" %(column2)s)
Result:  [('foo', None)]
```

Note:
`psycopg2.sql` is safe to SQL injection, `AsIs` probably not.
Testing using `'type': "varchar; DROP TABLE foo"` resulted in Postgres syntax error:

```
b'CREATE TABLE some_table_name\n ("column1" varchar; DROP TABLE foo,"column2" decimal)'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pct.py", line 28, in <module>
    cur.execute(createSQL, column_dict)
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 2:  ("column1" varchar; DROP TABLE foo,"column2" decimal)
```

Comment: This is not safe. I just tried to add on the the last column in the dictionary the adequate query, and it dropped the database.
Example:
'type': "decimal); DROP table some_table_name; create table some_table_name_2(aaaaa varchar(255)"


https://pastebin.pl/view/8bcb319b

Comment: Yeah, but is easy enough to test for: `';' in col_value`.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment, a complete example:

```
import psycopg2 
from psycopg2 import sql

columns = [{
    'name': 'column1',
    'type': 'varchar'
},
{
    'name': 'column2',
    'type': 'decimal'
}]

con = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test host=localhost user=aklaver") 
cur = con.cursor()

col_list = sql.SQL(',').join( [sql.Identifier(col["name"]) + sql.SQL(' ') + sql.SQL(col["type"]) for col in columns])
create_sql = sql.SQL("CREATE TABLE tablename ({})").format(col_list)

print(create_sql.as_string(con))                                                                                                                                          
CREATE TABLE tablename ("column1" varchar,"column2" decimal)

cur.execute(create_sql)
con.commit()


test(5432)=> \d tablename 
                   Table "public.tablename"
 Column  |       Type        | Collation | Nullable | Default 
---------+-------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 column1 | character varying |           |          | 
 column2 | numeric           |
```

Iterate over the column list of dicts and assign the column names as `SQL` identifiers and the column types as straight `SQL` into `sql.SQL` construct. Use this as parameter to `CREATE TABLE` `SQL`.

**Caveat**: `sql.SQL()` does not do escaping, so those values would have to be validated before they where used.